# TypeScript External Node Module Declaration File For Typings

Tags: node.js, module, typescript, commonjs, typing

I have a Node.js module (`index.js`) that has been transpiled with Babel to the code as follows:

```
// My stuff ...
var fs = require("fs");
var path = require("path");

exports.fileContent = fs.readFileSync(
  path.join(__dirname, "file.txt"),
  'utf8'
);

// Babel compiler stuff ...
Object.defineProperty(
  exports,
  "__esModule",
  { value: true }
);

// My stuff again ...
exports.default = exports.fileContent;
```

Usage in Node.js would be:

```
var myModule = require("my-module");

doSomethingWithIt( myModule.fileContent );
```

As far as I understand, I need to create a `.d.ts` declaration file and reference it in the `typings` field in my `package.json`. And also, this declaration file has to be a module. So my first approach after reading several tutorials about this topic was:

```
// index.d.ts

declare module "my-module" {
  export const fileContent: string;
  export default fileContent;
}
```

But sadly, this was a fail:

```
[...] error TS2656: Exported external package typings file 'index.d.ts' is not a module. [...]
```

My next approach was to get rid of the `declare module` thing:

```
export const fileContent: string;
export default fileContent;
```

This works for me, but however feels wrong as I did not find any `.d.ts` example file that is not using the `declare` stuff. I also noticed that I should not use `export default` in a namespace/module, which leads me to the point where I don’t understand how to declare the default export of my module at all.

Here are my questions:

- How do I do this the right way?
- How can I make sure that TypeScript recognizes the `default` property?
- Do I need to use the `declare module` stuff?
- Do I need to declare the imports (`fs` and `path`)?

---

**Edit:**

After a bit more researching and fiddling, I think I have found the solution by myself. As far as I understand, the external module description/declaration has to be a module—which means that it has to import or export something: In this case, it has to export the declaration and the declared constant as the default export as well:

```
export declare const fileContent: string;
export default fileContent;
```

Answer (score 0):

`error TS2656: ... is not a module` happens when trying to use ES6 style imports and the definition does not export a module.

I suggest changing your definition to

```
declare module MyModule {
    export const fileContent: string;
}

declare module "my-module" {
    export default MyModule
}
```

Since this definition is now "default exporting" a module, it can be imported using the default ES6 import syntax

```
import MyModule from "my-module"
```

Then use it

```
MyModule.fileContent...
```

Comment: Still throws the same error. I think I found out the working solution and I'll update my question.